# Removing a class in a CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, html, class, media-queries, stylesheet

I am trying to make my site mobile accessible. The problem I have is with the `nav`. I believe it has to do with the class being used on the `nav`. So what I want to do is remove the class when a mobile device is being used.

I have it in a media query and have changed a number of things to make it look correct on mobile. I read that it is possible to remove a class using

```
$( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass yourClass" );
```

I believe mine would be

```
$( "nav" ).removeClass( "navigation" );
```

but when put in the stylesheet and put through a css validator, I get

```
Lexical error at line 104, column 4.
Encountered: "(" (40), after : "$" ( "nav" ).removeClass( "navigation" );
```

I have no idea how to, or even if I can, fix this. Other pages I have read say this is impossible to do so I am getting conflicting information.

Here is me trying to post code.
This everything in my CSS affecting my nav.

```
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; }
header nav a { text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #a8e6a8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #228B22; }
nav a:link { color: #228B22; } 
nav a:visited { color: #568b22; } 
nav a:hover { color: #869DC7; 
    background-color: #EAEAEA; }
.navigation { float: right;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; }
```

Here is my unfinished media query.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #fff; }
  #wrapper { width: auto; min-width: 0; margin: 0; }
  h1 { margin: 0; text-align: center; font-size: 2em; line-height: 200%; }
  nav { float: none; width: auto; }
  nav li { display: inline-block; }
  nav a { padding: 1em; border-style: none; font-size: 1.2em; }
  nav ul { text-align: center; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  main { margin: 0; padding: 0 1em; font-size: 90%; }
  dd { margin-bottom: 1em; }
  footer { margin: 0; }
  .navigation { float: none;
    width: auto;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; };
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Scotty! ["How to ask?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) should give you all informations for how to make it "visually pleasing".

Comment: To the downvoters, it seems like the question was well described, just hidden by the new askers lack of knowledge of formatting.

Comment: I have no idea how that down vote happened, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you could add a class with [jQuery](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) but I don't believe this is the best way to achieve what you need.

What I have seen many designers doing is having two navs. One for big screens and another for small screens. It can be very handy, as you can work with different html codes too. For example, you can add FontAwesome icons to your mobile nav, add or remove links, etc. So, your html would look like this:

```
<nav class="nav-big">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="path">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="path">Link 2</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="nav-small">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><a href="path">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-minus"></i><a href="path">Link 2</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then, your CSS would look like this:

```
.nav-big {
...your styles 
}

.nav-small {
  ...your styles
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .nav-small {
      display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .nav-big {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You can see something like this working in my [Blog](http://virtuacreative.github.io/blog/) and also in another [website](http://virtuacreative.github.io/git/) I developed.

Hope to have helped. If I did, please mark the answer as useful or correct! Thanks!

Comment: Virtua, I am intrigued by the idea of multiple navs, but I cannot figure out how to implement it. I am new to coding and am not too great at it if I do say so myself. This site is my final project for the class I am taking and is due next week's Monday, 11/30. Do you think I have time to figure out the multiple navs and implement it into my site?
Thank you very much no matter what,
Scotty Coleman

Comment: Hey @Scotty, I'm not THE expert as well.. haha... I just share the knowledge I've acquired. And yes, you will certainly be able to set up your multiple navs in time. It is as simple as it looks like! ;) You will just need two, actually. Maybe instead of using a value of 1023px / 1024px you can use 736px / 737px; iPhone 6+ has a screen of 736px (portrait), so you will probably not find larger portrait screens around. Feel free to contact me via [website](http://virtuacreative.github.io/git/contact.html) if you need more specific help.

Comment: Look, [this guy here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/big-menus-small-screens-responsive-multi-level-navigation--webdesign-8452) goes deep into the subject. Is a little bit complicated, but can be followed. If you want something simpler, you can use [Refills](http://refills.bourbon.io/) with the technique of `display: none;` I've told you about. This is the way I build [this website](http://virtuacreative.github.io/git/) from scratch, with [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) and Refills.

Comment: I will contact you through your website. That is, if I can find my way through the Portuguese haha.

Comment: Hahaha... I'm sure you'll be fine, it's quite intuitive! Cheers! :D

Comment: I sent you a message.

Comment: Ok Scotty, I received. I'll reply to you soon! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on board! Please try to be more concise on your questions :-)

My answer:
The code you're posting is JavaScript. [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), to be precise. This certainly doesn't work in CSS.

But the better solution is to use the media query not to *remove* a class, but to *alter* it. Example:

```
.foo { width:200px; }
@media print
{
  .foo { width:100px; }
}
```

EDIT after the CSS was added to the question:

The trailing `;` looks like a syntax error to me: Change `letter-spacing: 0.1em; };` to `letter-spacing: 0.1em; }`

Other than that the media query looks good in principle. Try adding `background:red` to see if it works at all :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas, but, as I still can't get it to work, would it be ok if I tried to show you my code by adding it to my question? ( I have have no idea why that downvote happened, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

`$("nav").removeClass("navigation");` is JavaScript, not CSS. Conceptually, you can not add/remove a class in CSS - it is only a *style description language*.

What you **can** do in CSS, however, is show/hide content for a specific device width (*"breakpoint"*):

```
.navigation {
  display: block;
  /* your style definitions for nav */
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
  .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
}
```